# Send XML via Put with CakePHP

Tags: api, cakephp, rest, put

I want to send a put request to an API which wants the details of the request as XML

Apparently I need to send the xml as a file when using PUT with PHP.

How can I do this?

Here is what I'm trying:

```
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
$result = $HttpSocket->put($put, $fh);
```

where $put is the url and $fh is a file i have made on the fly like this

```
$xmlObject = Xml::fromArray($xmlArray);
$xmlString = $xmlObject->asXML();

$fh = fopen('php://memory', 'rw');  
fwrite($fh, $xmlString);  
rewind($fh);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this just using php rather than the php helpers

```
# write data into a temporary file
$putData = "<subscription><productPath>$new_product_path</productPath></subscription>";
$putDataFile = tmpfile();
fwrite($putDataFile, "<subscription><productPath>$new_product_path</productPath></subscription>");
fseek($putDataFile, 0);

# initialize PUT call
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $putDataFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($putData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

# executes PUT call and clean up
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
fclose($putDataFile);
curl_close($ch);
```

I'd have preferred using the Cake classes for neatness, but this works with the api i was using.

Answer (score 3):

I've tested it on cake 2.0.5, and HttpSocket::put can send key-value arrays or raw strings as postdata.

So, you can send the xml string directly, and the remote server will read it in Raw Post Data i. e. `file_get_contents("php://input")`

This works:

```php
$http = new HttpSocket();
$xml_data = Xml::fromArray($data);
$xml_string = $xml_data->asXML();
$response = $http->put('http://example.com', $xml_string);
```

To demonstrate it, I've created a Controller called RequestXmlTestController filed under `'Controllers/RequestXmlTestController.php'` (code is below), and an empty view filed under `'RequestXmlTests/index.ctp'`

Controller code:

```php
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * RequestXmlTest Controller
 *
 */
class RequestXmlTestController extends AppController {
/**
 * Use no Model
 */
  public $uses = array();

/**
 * index action
 */
  public function index(){
    App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
    App::uses('Xml', 'Utility');
    $http = new HttpSocket();

    $data = array(
      'type' => array('name' => 'Campaign', 'data' => array(
        array('name' => 'Come eat at Joe\'s', 'products' => array('adserver', 'analytics'))
      ))
    );
    $xml_data = Xml::fromArray($data);
    $xml_string = $xml_data->asXML();
    $response = $http->put(Router::url(array('action' => 'test'), true), $xml_string);
    debug($response);
  }

/**
 * test action
 *   Test the requests and dump Raw Post Data and Cake's Request object
 */
  public function test(){
    var_dump(array('raw_post_data' => file_get_contents("php://input")));
    echo "\n\n";
    var_dump($this->request);
    exit;
    $this->render('index');
  }

}
```

References:
 [HttpSocket Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/httpsocket.html)

Comment: Thanks Lourenzo, Sending it as a string didn't work when sending it to an external service (not written in php  / cake or under my control)    - the tech support people there said i must send a file, not a string.

Comment: @Will, I think you need to know which data format is expected, encoding, etc.

I've worked once with a .NET SOAP WebService that expected a file as a ByteArray, and took more time that I wanted to put it together.